# Cancel Alamofire.request not working (Swift)

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

I have a function for uploading a string in base64 to a server using Alamofire, and I want the user to be able to cancel the upload.

I am currently trying with `.cancel()` but I guess I am approaching this method incorrectly because it does not cancel the request made.

Code:

```
var uploadVerificateRequest: Alamofire.Request?

func uploadVerificate(_ pdf: Data, completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: [String: AnyObject]) -> ()) {
    var jsonData: [String: AnyObject]?

    let PDFBase64 = pdf.base64EncodedString()
    
    let verificateParameters = [
        "Base64Image": PDFBase64
    ] as [String : Any]
    
    self.uploadVerificateRequest = Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: verificateParameters)
        .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = value as! [String: AnyObject]
                
                jsonData = json
                
                if let jsonData = jsonData {
                    completionHandler(jsonData)
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler([:])
                }
            }
    }
}

func cancelUploadVerificate() {
    self.uploadVerificateRequest?.cancel()
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another thing, when printing self.uploadVerificateRequest.task after calling cancel(), I receive "<__NSCFLocalDataTask: 0x7fcdcee1d2b0>{ taskIdentifier: 8 } { canceling }" in the console, so the cancel() call itself seems to work, but the request still keeps running.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution which seems to work after some testing:

```
func cancelUploadVerificate() {
    self.uploadVerificateRequest.session.getAllTasks { tasks in
        tasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you test this? I have similar code but in a singleton shared instance.

Answer (score 0):

Call cancel on the task:

```
self.uploadVerificateRequest?.task?.cancel()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I also tried with self.uploadVerificateRequest?.task?.suspend() but it still keeps running.

Comment: Also, var uploadVerificateRequest is always nil while the data is being uploaded and after it's done. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:

```
self.uploadVerificateRequest = Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: verificateParameters)
self.uploadVerificateRequest.responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = value as! [String: AnyObject]

            jsonData = json

            if let jsonData = jsonData {
                completionHandler(jsonData)
            }
            else {
                completionHandler([:])
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: When I try this I receive the error "Value of type 'Request?' has no member 'responseJSON'". Outside of the function I am still using var uploadVerificateRequest: Alamofire.Request?. :/